# C# Edit a Textfile

Tags: c#, text-files, edit, discord.net

```
    [Command("ping")]
    public async Task Ping()
    {
        using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText("config.txt"))
        {
            int points = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
            var pingembed = new EmbedBuilder()
            {
                //Optional color
                Color = Color.Green,
                Title = " Pong!",
                Description = "Bot | " + points + ":0 | Users"
            };
            await ReplyAsync("", false, pingembed.Build());

            string configpoints = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(reader.ReadLine()));
            configpoints = configpoints.Remove(1).Insert(1, Convert.ToString(points = points + 1));
        }                                
    }
```

I'm creating a Discord Bot. The command "ping" send a Embed. In the description of the Embed there's a Integer called points and everytime when someone is using the "ping" command the value of points should get +1.
The value of points is inside a Textfile called config.txt. In the moment i'm trying to remove the value of points(the value is 1) and insert the new value(the value should be 2).

Comment: And what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to write the file again.. It's a one liner to read and write a file that only stores the number of the ping..

```
File.WriteAllText(
  @"c:\temp\ping.txt",    
  (int.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\ping.txt"))+1).ToString()
);
```

If your file contains other stuff you'll need to be more involved with your reading and writing...